# Stateful EJB does not keep property value

Tags: jsf, session, jakarta-ee, ejb, stateful

I am using a stateful EJB for keeping my login information:

```
@Stateful
public class SecurityService {

    private static final Logger log4jLogger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityService.class);

    @Inject UtenteDao utenteDao;
    @Inject AutorizzazioneDao autorizzazioneDao;

    private Utente utenteCorrente;

    private Negozio negozioCorrente;

    public SecurityService() {

    }

    public boolean authenticate() {

        boolean result = false;

        Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal!=null) {
            utenteCorrente = utenteDao.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        }

        if (negozioCorrente!=null && utenteCorrente!=null) {
            Autorizzazione a = autorizzazioneDao.cercaPerNegozioAndUtente(negozioCorrente, utenteCorrente);
            result = a!=null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

// ...
    }

My JSF login page is controlled by:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController {

@Inject private SecurityService securityService;

private String username;    
private String password;

private Negozio negozio;

public void login() throws IOException {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

    try {

        if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            request.logout();
        }
        request.login(username, password);

        securityService.setNegozioCorrente(negozio);
        if (!securityService.authenticate()) {
            throw new ServletException("Utente non abilitato.");
        }

        externalContext.redirect("/pippo/");

    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Accesso Negato"));        
    }
}

public void logout() throws IOException {
//...

}

public String getLoggedUsername() {
    Utente utenteCorrente = securityService.getUtenteCorrente();
    String fullName = "";
    if (utenteCorrente!=null) {
        fullName = utenteCorrente.getNomeCompleto();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Utente NULLO");
    }
    return fullName;
}
//...
```

}

My users actually can login the way I want (programmatic security with some adds from my domain).

The problem I have is in the next page, when you're already logged in. I want to display in all pages header "Welcome! You're logged in as `#{loginController.loggedUsername}`.

I keep getting a **null** `securityService.getUtenteCorrente()`.

SecurityService EJB behaves like a Stateless session bean! I want to know whether I am misunderstanding something about the Stateful EJBs, or I just omitted something for this to work as I expect.

My goal is just to have a "session-wide" bean for keeping user state. Is a EJB necessary or can I just use a SessionScoped JSF ManagedBean?

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LoginController` is request-scoped and your `SecurityService` is dependent-scoped (for all purposes it is not session-scoped unless you specify it as such). Therefore, when the second JSF page references the `LoginController` in a EL expression, a new instance of `LoginController` would be created that would have a reference to a different instance of the `SecurityService` SFSB.

If you need to access the original `SecurityService` instance, you should mark it as `@SessionScoped` so that clients like the `LoginController` can access them across requests. But then, you might also want to consider why you need a `@Stateful` annotation in the first place, since this task could be done by an `@SessionScoped` managed bean. You don't really need a SFSB to store a reference to your User/Principal objects.

Comment: ok, thank you. It works now but you made me think. I read something about Stateful and Stateless but still can't find a valid use case for Stateful in a simple web application. Maybe you can suggest me one? I already use Stateless for having EJBs (and transactional methods then).

Comment: @FabioB.: SFSBs are usually used with CDI conversations, since only SFSBs can reference an extended persistence context. In a web-app, this is usually where you'd use a SFSB to manage the persistence context in a transactional manner across possibly several HTTP requests. A typical usecase would be a JSF component (like a wizard) that references a SFSB to manage the state of the wizard, backed by a database.

Comment: here's a very useful S.O. user! :)

Answer (score -2):

In order to be managed session beans must be declared using the `@EJB` annotation or looked up using the JNDI, the way you inject it just gives you a plain object not managed by the app server, in fact you create a new object any time you use it.

Comment: You're right, I've misunderstood the difference between `@EJB` end `@Inject`. Thanks to @Vineet for the thorough explanation.