# Why session beans are called so?

Tags: java, ejb, session-bean

As I see in examples, every java class can be defined as a session bean in ejb, even if there is no http session defined and used inside them. So, why are they called session beans?

Comment: Well, it's not called `HttpSessionBean`. There are other sessions.

Comment: Indeed, "session" != "HTTP session". A "session" is just the context wherein multiple closely related requests/conversations/queries/etc can take place. In case of EJBs, a single "session" must be interpreted in context of a single DB transaction (while in case of HTTP, a single session must be interpreted in context of a single webbrowser instance). Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/8889612#8889612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session bean performs operations, such as calculations or database access, for the client. . Session bean objects either can be stateless or can maintain conversational state across methods and transactions.

**A stateless session** bean is an object that does not have an associated conversational state, but may have instance state

In **Stateful session bean**, the instance variables represent the state of unique client-bean sessions. The interaction of the client with bean is called as conversational state.

No matter whether a session bean is statelss or stateful they mantain some kind of session, which may last for a single call or may last for mulitple bean calls. Hence they are called Session beans.

Answer (score 1):

They could also somewhat less accurately have been called "transaction" beans. Each entry-point method is executed within the context of an isolated session with a back-end system, which is most typically, but not necessarily, a database.