# Encapsulating stateless beans inside a stateful session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, stateless-session-bean, stateful-session-bean

I have a Java EE application using EJBs, and perform most of the functions through Stateless EJBs.

I have a requirement for all users to also have an active session, and I'm wondering what the best way of using the beans are.

Currently, I have a command line client which uses the stateless beans directly in addition to logging into the system with the stateful bean.

I'm wondering if I should have the client perform all functions through the stateful bean, that way no functions can be performed unless an active session exists.
This makes more sense to me personally.

I'm just not quite sure what design is 'right' or what is the better design.
If I continue to have the client use the stateless beans, then I'll have to have a way for those stateless beans to check if the client has an active session.

Comment: Why do you need a *stateful* session bean for logging? What else is in your session (= what is the requirement)?

Comment: It's for logging in, authentication. Basically all the system functions are a part of the same session (a user needs to be logged in before any functions can be performed)

Answer (score 0):

A session exists anyway even if you're only invoking stateless beans. The choice on whether to invoke a stateless or stateful bean should mater only whether you need to keep state between method invocations. Try injecting the `SessionContext` and notice that there will be a principal, even if it's anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is an authenticated user, a stateless session bean is fine:

- You can call `SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` in the EJB (for logging purposes etc.)
- You can impose authorization declaratively (using the `@RolesAllowed` annotation on EJB methods)

so I don't see a reason to switch to stateful session beans. It might not be relevant, but a stateful session bean consumes resources on the server side, so there should be a compelling reason to do so.

A related question [When to use Stateful session bean over Stateless session bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18000431/2390083) received no answers up to today, and I consider *no answer* in this case to be *an answer as well*.