# Injecting a session-scoped bean in JSF2

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, cdi, jaas, session-scope

I'm having some difficulty interacting with a Session-scoped managed bean after a user programmatically logs into my web application.

BACKGROUND:

I have a [javax.enterprise.context.]Session-scoped bean named "SessionHelper" where I place a lot of information gathered from the user as he/she uses the application.  In my logon page (which is **NOT** SessionScoped), Here's a sample of what I'm doing:

```
@Inject SessionHelper theHelper;
....
FacesContext theContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = theContext.getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest theRequest = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
....
theRequest.login(username, password);
....
theSession.method(dostuff);
```

After this section of code is executed, my application redirects into a protected directory and allows the user (based on roles) to perform their job functions.

When I attempt to "@Inject SessionHelper" into any of my protected resources, my understanding is that I should get the specific SessionScoped instance of SessionHelper that has the data set right after the call to login.  This should be available to me for as long as the session (for that specific user) is valid.  Unfortunately, the instance I'm getting has none of my "theSession.method(dostuff)" in it.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the scope here?

The only thing I could potentially see is that the initial @Inject into my login page is not carried over after the session has been created.  If this is the case, is there a way to force a re-injection after the session is created?

As always, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: No.  The sample code I've added above is not in a Session scoped bean.

Comment: it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for your reply!  Unfortunately this doesn't help.  I'm basically already doing what Balus suggested: storing data in a Session-scoped managed bean.

Comment: Do you have the correct sessionScoped? Maybe your helper is just wrong

Comment: The helper has the correct SessionScoped class (javax.enterprise.context.)