# What is the difference between Stateless Session Beans and Request Scoped beans

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, scope, ejb, cdi

I know that *Stateless Session Beans* refers to EJB beans while Request Scoped refer to CDI beans (or JSF managed beans), so I will start by giving their both definitions from the [Java EE Tutoriel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html).

[Stateless Session Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html#gipin) definition:

> A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with
>   the client. When a client invokes the methods of a stateless bean, the
>   bean’s instance variables may contain a state specific to that client
>   but only for the duration of the invocation. When the method is
>   finished, the client-specific state should not be retained.

CDI [Request Scoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html) definition:

> A user’s interaction with a web application in a single HTTP request.

What I understood from both definitions is that the concept of stateless session beans is the same as the request scope concept, but I'm not realy sure because the naming *"session"* confused me. So, I asked my self if this were the case (same concept) maybe they would have a similar naming (using *request* instead of *session*).

So, my question is: Is there any conceptual difference between EJB stateless session beans and CDI/JSF request scoped beans?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the/ Or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/? Do note that in EJB context the "client" is not the webbrowser, but the managed bean where the EJB is been injected. This part is where many webdev starters fall over.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a big difference.

A stateless EJB doesn't maintain state between invocations. It typically doesn't have state at all, except for dependencies on other beans. It offers a service to other components. The clients of a stateless bean can invoke it to serve an HTTP request, but they could also call it outside of any HTTP request (in a batch, a scheduled job, or whatever).

A request-scoped bean typically has a state (otherwise, it could be an application-scoped bean or a stateless bean). And this state lasts for the duration of an HTTP request. It can not be invoked outside of the HTTP request handling code.
A good example for a request-scoped bean would be the current user:

- a request comes to a servlet filter
- the servlet filter extracts a cookie from the request and fetches the current user information related to this cookie from the database (by calling, for example, a stateless bean)
- the servlet filter stores the user information into the "currentUser" request-scoped bean
- the other components involved in the same request handling can get the current user information from this injected currentUser bean.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I still have a small question, regarding what you said the behavior of statless bean is then similar to any class that doesn't have any annotation? I understand that there is aother benefits for marking it `@stateless` but is the behavior similar to any normal not annotated classes?

Comment: @stateless means it will be managed by the ejb container, which offers benefits like thread safety thanks to pooling