# Java EE beans and volatile keyword

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans, cdi, volatile

Servlet, EJB and CDI parts of Java EE specification describe bean management (injection and etc..). But also specification does not describe (explicitly or implicitly) concurrency properties of the bean container. If I've used WildFly or GlassFish, then the Java EE application server can access to bean object more from one thread.

So the question is, do have I to use `volatile` keyword with all bean fields, which theoretically can be accessed from more than one thread (i.e. for almost all beans, and, at least, for all fields annotated with `@Inject`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical answer depends on kind of bean and kind of property, but normally you don't need to worry about this at all.

In case of EJBs, the container already enforces some default concurrency control which you can control by `@Lock` and `@ConcurrencyManagement` annotations. See also a.o. [EJB @Asynchronous to retrieve real time inserted row in JSF seems to be thread locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754603/ejb-asynchronous-to-retrieve-real-time-inserted-row-in-jsf-seems-to-be-thread-l/).

In case of JPA entities, any need for concurrency control suggests a major design/fundamental problem. Concurrency control should only be enforced in the controller, not the model nor the view. JPA entities themselves do in no way represent the "controller". In other words, a `volatile` field in a JPA entity doesn't make any sense, while a `volatile` field in a managed bean referring the JPA entity itself might make sense.

In case of managed beans (JSF/CDI), usually if you come to a point you worry about concurrency on some managed bean, it's much more likely that the scope of the bean is wrong and needs to be narrowed down. E.g. using `@ViewScoped` or `@ConversationScoped` instead of `@SessionScoped` or even `@ApplicationScoped`. See also a.o. [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

In case of application scoped beans ("singletons" [in widest sense](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne)), it may make sense, but only if there doesn't already exist a concurrent/atomic wrapper class for the field of interest, such as `ConcurrentMap`, `AtomicBoolean`, etcetera. See also a.o. [Concurrency of @ApplicationScoped JSF managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009907/concurrency-of-applicationscoped-jsf-managed-beans/).

Comment: For example, my jsf-web-application uses ajax requests, so they (AJAX requests) are asynchronous by nature, and in one time there can be many requests from the view on browser client to the server. Can I assume that the server will respond to queries from one thread?

Comment: > "In case of EJBs, the container already enforces some default concurrency control which you can control by Lock and ConcurrencyManagement annotations".

How in that case the container resolves visibility problem? When one thread constructs the bean and injects dependencies, and the other one calls method, which can access injected fields, JVM does not guarantee that actual reference stored in non-volatile field will be visible to other threads.

Comment: JSF ajax story is elaborated and sub-linked in last link in last paragraph. As to EJBs, they are injected as proxies referring a pool of instances not as actual instances. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25514361 The same is true for CDI managed beans (but not for JSF managed beans; however it isn't possible to inject a narrower scoped JSF managed bean in a broader scoped JSF managed bean, so that excludes potential concurrency trouble). Again the first paragraph in my answer still stands: normally you don't need to worry about this all.