# @Inject stateless EJB contains data from previous request

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs, stateless-session-bean

I have a JAX-RS webservice with a resource for generating testdata. During tests  I found out, that the injected EJB is not reinitialized and still contains data from the last request.

I have a jar file `server.jar` containing my business logic with EJBs. To show my problem I have created a stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
public class TestService
{
    @EJB
    SubsequentTestService state2Service;

    private String value;

    public void testIt()
    {
        System.out.println("####### VALUE: " + value);
        value = "TestValue";

        state2Service.testIt();
    }
}
```

I am using the subsequent call to `SubsequentTestService` to show the odd behaviour also exists for call of another stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class SubsequentTestService
{
    private String value;

    public void testIt()
    {
        System.out.println("####### VALUE2: " + value);
        value = "TestValue2";
    }
}
```

Changing the annotation form `@EJB` to `@Inject` does not change anything.

In my `web.war` I have simple JAX-RS beans. The one which is called to show the strange behaviour is defined as follows:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource
{
    @Inject
    TestService testService;

    @GET
    @Path("/state")
    public void testState()
    {
        testService.testIt();
    }
}
```

The JAX-RS application configuration looks as follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRsConfiguration extends Application
{
}
```

The war file contains the beans.xml, but no other configuration file. Everything is packaged into an ear file and is deployed in wildfly 10.0.0.Final. If I call the webservice as GET request via http://localhost:8080/api/test/state I get the expected output:

> INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) ####### VALUE: null
>   INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) ####### VALUE2: null

But on the second request I get following unexpected output:

> INFO  [stdout] (default task-8) ####### VALUE: TestValue
>   INFO  [stdout] (default task-8) ####### VALUE2: TestValue2

What is my problem here? Might be anything misconfigured in the wildfly? But I have only changed the logging and the datasource definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the meaning of `@Stateless` backwards.

This does not mean like so:

> *Hey container, here's an arbitrary class, please make it a stateless bean.*

This actually means like so:

> *Hey container, here's a stateless class, you can safely use it as a stateless bean.*

You have a stateful class. You should mark it as a `@Stateful` bean. Otherwise, get rid of all the state (unmanaged instance variables) so you can safely use it as a `@Stateless` bean.

#### See also:

- [Why Stateless session beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809855/why-stateless-session-beans/31639830#31639830)
- [JSF request scoped bean keeps recreating new Stateful session beans on every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/)
- [When using @EJB, does each managed bean get its own @EJB instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514361/when-using-ejb-does-each-managed-bean-get-its-own-ejb-instance/)

Comment: Shame on me. There are days where you better do not leave the bed. Thanks for your clarification.